# Use toast as CC with text to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'd like to know if there is a way to use Toast as CC (Subtitling) when using Text to speech.
The problem is not for a specific text, that could be shown at the same time, but showing CC at the right time.
I think that TTS queue could help, but couldn't figure out how that could work.

TIA!
Milton

**Edit 1**
I want to use toast as Subtitling (CC). Show the same text sent to tts, in toast msg.

**Edit 2**
Ok, let me explain the idea: Suppose I've a text that comes from a service, and I enqueue every text I can get from that service, and make os speech to the user. That's ok, and works. Now I'd like to add subtitles of what the tts is saying. Suppose that I've got 3 texts from the service, `["This is the first text", "This is the second text", "This is the third text"]`, and I enqueue it to the tts. The os will speech it all, one at a time. But If I do the same with toast, the only one that I could see will be the last one, because toast doesn't queue the messages, one toast overrides the previous. Maybe there is a way to enqueue the messages and that's the solution. So, I'd like to show a toast (with the enqueued text) for a time, that I can estimate based on the tts speed and text length. Make more sense now ?

Comment: Am I the only who thinks it's non-obvious what CC means?

Comment: In case it's about the toasts: here is my Toast replacement that will allow you to cancel, or replace a Toast, before it expires - [`Boast` on github gist](https://gist.github.com/mobiRic/9786993)

Comment: reinvent toast (a custom pop up dialoge box) for this job ... toast is made for "once in a while" alert ..

Comment: Looks like a good point :). So I can create a custom Toast with queue and timing. I'll share that when got it. Any other idea ?

Comment: Milton, thanks, I've wanted an excuse to play with TTS for years, but not got round to it. So now I have a TTS demo (based on a blog post I found) that I modified to do exactly what I think you are after. It `Boasts` each line as the device speaks it.

Comment: Milton, any luck with the solution I provided?

Comment: Richard, It's no longer a requirement for me, so I didn't tried. I think your answer could be helpful for others! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on API 15+, by combining the [`UtteranceProgressListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html) with my [`Boast`](https://gist.github.com/mobiRic/9786993) class.

The `Boast` is a drop-in replacement for `Toast` that allows for cancellation of a current Toast, or replacing the current Toast. This means the toasts do not queue up, but will display exactly when you want them to.

How to know when to display them?

API 15+ gives us the `UtteranceProgressListener` that you can set on your [`TextToSpeech`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) instance:

- [`TextToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceProgressListener%28android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener%29)

Use the `UtteranceProgressListener.onStart()` method to trigger the CC `Boast` playback. Note that `Boast` or `Toast` needs to be called on the main (UI) thread.

Below some code snippets that should illustrate the idea.

---

I called my main activity `SubtitleTextToSpeechDemo`. Check for TTS by sending the correct intent in `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // check to TTS
    Intent ttsInstallCheck = new Intent();
    ttsInstallCheck.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(ttsInstallCheck, TTS_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

This code will return to `TtsDemoActivity` in `onActivityResult()`. Here we set up the listener to show the `Boast`s and log the utterance:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (TTS_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode)
    {
        if (TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS == resultCode)
        {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onStart(final String utteranceId)
                {
                    SubtitleTextToSpeechDemo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Boast.showText(TtsDemoActivity.this, utteranceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("mobiRic", "start: " + utteranceId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId)
                {
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // not installed
        }
    }
}
```

---

In order to start speaking, I make calls from the `OnInitListener` callback:

```
/**
 * TextToSpeech.OnInitListener callback is called when the TTS engine has initialised.
 */
public void onInit(int i)
{
    doSpeak("Hello Milton");
    doSpeak("Here is the answer");
    doSpeak("each utterance triggers the listener");
    doSpeak("so you can Boast about it");
}
```

Method `doSpeak()` is just a helper method because we need to pass that `HashMap` of parameters to each call, in order to identify each utterance. For convenience, I use the actual text as the key:

```
private void doSpeak(String text)
{
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // use the actual text as the key to ID the utterance
    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
}
```

---

I should credit James Elsey's demo TTS project on github that showed me the boilerplate TTS setup code:

- https://github.com/jameselsey/TextToSpeechDemo
- [related blog post](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-a-really-easy-tutorial-on-how-to-use-text-to-speech-tts-and-how-you-can-enter-text-and-have-it-spoken/)

I have uploaded my full working code to this gist:

- [mobiRic / Subtitle Text-To-Speech demo](https://gist.github.com/mobiRic/eb03ef954d673c09dabf)

Comment: @Jimmy thanks for the original code that I used to get started in this answer.